# Formatting pandas output data

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

I have a dataframe and want the output to be formatted to save paper for printing.

```
       GameA    GameB
Country     
London     5    20
London     5    10
London     3    5
London     3    6
London          8
London          40
France     2    20
France     2    22
France     3    
France     3    
France     3    
USA        10
```

Is there a way to format the dataframe to look like this:

```
    GameA              GameB
Country             
London  5       London  20
London  5       London  10
London  3       London  5
London  3       London  6
London          London  8
London          London  40

       GameA            GameB
France  2       France  20
France  2       France  22
France  3           
France  3           
France  3           

       GameA            
USA   10
```

Answer (score 0):

The formatting is off a bit because of how it copy and pasted the text results above (due to the missing values), but this should work with your actual data.

```
countries = df.index.unique()

for country in countries:
    print(df.loc[df.index == country])
    print(' ')

         GameA  GameB
Country              
London       5     20
London       5     10
London       3      5
London       3      6
London       8    NaN
London      40    NaN

         GameA  GameB
Country              
France       2     20
France       2     22
France       3    NaN
France       3    NaN
France       3    NaN

         GameA  GameB
Country              
USA         10    NaN
```

Comment: is there a way to output the results to a CSV using`to_csv` or something?